# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process and Markov property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

There isn't a similar question in the forum, so here it goes.

Firstly, let the O-U **velocity** process be defined as 
$$
dV_t = -\beta V_t dt + \sigma dB_t
$$
with $V_0 = v$, and $B = (B_t), t \geq 0$ a Brownian motion. Additionally, let the O-U **position** process be defined as
$$
dX_t = V_tdt
$$
with $X_0 = x_0$.

In the literature, it is widely taken for granted that $V_t$ **is a Markov process**, but $X_t$ **is not**.

**How can these two things be proved?**

And a bonus question: if we add the velocity process to the position process, thus obtaining an O-U position-velocity process $(X,V) = ((X_t,V_t))_{t \geq 0}$, why is this Markov?

Thanks very much

Comment: Try to prove this when $V=B$. The idea is the same hence if you have trouble finding the proof that X is not Markov but (X,V) is Markov in this simpler setting, this is the case you should be looking at.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can usually write the unique strong solution of the first SDE as :
$ V_t = e^{\beta t}V_0 + \sigma \int_0^t e^{\beta s}dB_s =e^{\beta t}v + \sigma \int_0^t e^{\beta s}dB_s$
Then what do you think about the second term in the RHS?
The question about the non-Markovianity of $X$ follows from the previous calculus

Comment: if anything, $V_t = e^{-\beta t}v + \sigma e^{-\beta t}\int_0^t \! e^{\beta s} \, \mathrm{d}B_s$, so I'm afraid your expression for $V_t$ is not correct. Moreover, you answer is not very rigorous so it unfortunately does not really suit me.

Comment: Adam, i'm afraid I supposed your question was well-posed.
Actually, you wrote the SDE $dV_t =\beta V_tdt + \sigma dB_t $ . My answer is correct regarding this equation, but I agree that OU-Process is usually defined as the solution of $dV_t =-\beta V_tdt + \sigma dB_t $, in which case your answer is right...

Comment: correction added ;)

Comment: @Adam so if $- \beta$ is $<0$, we have that the process is non markovian, otherwise it is ? I am asking because there is no answer to that question